# "No qualifying bean of type [play.cache.CachedAction] is defined" error in Play Framework with Spring configuration

Tags: spring, caching, dependency-injection, playframework-2.0

I have a Play Framework 2.3 project that configure to use [Spring as DI library](https://github.com/zarinfam/play-java-spring-jpa-rest). When i use @Cached on my controller i encountered the following error:

```
`No qualifying bean of type [play.cache.CachedAction] is defined`
```

How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I add `CachedAction` bean to Spring configuration as a bean and now everything is ok.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"controllers","services", "daos"})
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public CachedAction getCachedAction() {
        return new CachedAction();
    }
}
```